# How do I prevent my data from being corrupted on a network drive?

Tags: database, corruption

I've been cracking my head this week over a problem I have with my applications at work.

I made a few apps that run on multiple computers and read/write data from a network drive.

The data is usually just a few kilobytes in size and changes every few seconds, so I thought text files were the easiest and fastest way to do it.

The problem is that the data (or text files) often gets, corrupt?
While some computers show the correct data, others will show older data (usually from a few minutes before) or don't show anything at all. When checking the contents of the text files on multiple computers they often show different data even though it is the same file on the network drive.

Could it be that the file gets corrupted because multiple instances are writing and reading data at a fast pace to the same file?

The problem is easily fixed by deleting/re-creating the files or move them to another folder, but it is a real pain to do this every now and then.

Setting up an SQL server is not the solution for now because I'm still waiting for permission.

Maybe I should try SQLite or any other type of database for now?
Or maybe there is an easier fix to get rid of this problem, anyone had this problem before?

Comment: are those files shared by multiple users?

Comment: @Plutonix yes, multiple users share the same file(s)

Comment: Unless you are simply appending, the only way to "update" a text file is to write the entire thing back out.  That makes it very, very easy for 2+ users to overwrite each others changes and write out stale data.  The Solution depends on the nature of the data.

Comment: Text files are not designed to be multi-user databases. When there are free implementations of many real databases available, why would you resort to an unreliable plain text file implementation?

Comment: They usually overwrite the data and don't append. The amount of 'lines' always stay the same, the content just changes.

Comment: @KenWhite Because I never really had to make use of databases for my small applications and I'm still an amateur. Besides an SQL server, are there any other reliable multi-user databases?

Comment: There are dozens of reliable multi-user databases. However, you can't ask here for a recommendation for them. That would be specifically indicated as being off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines. Google can find information on available DBMS systems for Windows.